# Problem adding inputs to panel using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that the button stops working for the following panels. I guess it's an id problem, but I have no idea how to fix it (I know very little about javascript)

Html:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <button id="Addpanel">Add panel</button>
</div>
```

My scripts:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#Addpanel').click(function(){
            var newDiv = $('<div class="panel-default"><br /><div class="form-control"><input type="text" id="fieldnum" name="fieldnum" value="">Fill number<a type="button" id="filldetails" class="btn" onclick="addFields()">Add</a></div><div id="container" class="form-control" />'
            );
            $(".card-body").append(newDiv);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Second:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function addFields(){
        var number = document.getElementById("fieldnum").value;
        var container = document.getElementById("container");

        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = "input" + (i+1);
            input.className = "form-control";
            container.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If the button is clicked multiple times, indeed there will be more than one element with same id, that is not allowed in html.

Comment: @LucaKiebel try clicking on the `Add` `a` element.

Comment: @Esko well, it's *allowed* but not a very good idea. Pretty much anything that looks stuff up by ID will assume there is only one and only fetch the first one, so code that relies on ID will most likely not be applied to later duplicated IDs. But the page itself doesn't stop working if there are duplicates.

Comment: Do you mean that when you click on the `Add` link, nothing happens?

Comment: @LucaKiebel there is an `<a>` element in the appended HTML: `<a type="button" id="filldetails" class="btn" onclick="addFields()">Add</a>`

Comment: Exactly, the problem is when i try to click "add"

Comment: @vlaz It is [not allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute): ***The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.***. You can easily check it also with the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: @Esko there is a difference here - you *can have* HTML with duplicate IDs. You can easily check that by making having any HTML with duplicate IDs and trying to show render it in a browser. It will *not be valid* but will also *not break* the page and the browser will still display it. It is therefore *allowed* content to me because you can type it in and the browser accepts the input. Being invalid, will likely cause most, if not all, functionality that relies on the ID to behave oddly and/or fail in different ways.

Comment: @vlaz Not going to continue the discussion here any further, but my definition of valid is valid as stated in the specification. You can't define "not rendered" as the only criteria for being valid, it might be rendered but javascript might break, or css not work as it should, there are number of things that can go wrong if nothing is as is stated in the specification. You know this if you code for the web.

Comment: @Esko `You can't define "not rendered" as the only criteria for being valid` and I don't define that as "valid". In fact, I've repeatedly stated *it's invalid*, so I don't know why you decided to twist my words there. I said it's ***allowed*** based on the fact that it's being rendered. My definition of "allowed" is that it's not rejected by the browser. The spec defines what is *valid* while the browser accepts or rejects certain input. These are two different concepts. Accepted (allowed) content can be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should use like this:

```
$(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $('#Addpanel').click(function () {
        var newDiv = $('<div class="panel-default"><br /><div class="form-control"><input type="text" id="fieldnum' + count + '" name="fieldnum" value="">Fill number<a type="button" id="filldetails' + count + '" class="btn" onclick="addFields()">Add</a></div><div id="container' + count + '" class="form-control" />');
        $(".card-body").append(newDiv);
        count++;
    });
});
```